# Update data frame table values based on plotly frame value

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I have a plotly plot showing the columns `time` and `amount` of the dataframe `df`.

df:

```
id   time                 amount    category
1    2018-03-22 15:22:00  78        g1        
2    2018-03-22 15:30:00  77        g1
...   
34   2018-03-23 01:00:00  82        k3 
...
```

The plot is an animation so the plot appears step by step like in this example (https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/#cumulative-lines-animation) in section **Cumulative Lines Animation**. I cannot post my coding but it looks similar to this.

Coding from the website:

```
library(plotly)

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

d <- txhousing %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area")) %>%
  accumulate_by(~date)

p <- d %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~date, 
    y = ~median,
    split = ~city,
    frame = ~frame, 
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines', 
    line = list(simplyfy = F)
  ) %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = "Date",
      zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      title = "Median",
      zeroline = F
    )
  ) %>% 
  animation_opts(
    frame = 100, 
    transition = 0, 
    redraw = FALSE
  ) %>%
  animation_slider(
    hide = T
    ) %>%
  animation_button(
    x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
  )
```

My plot:
[image: Plotly Animation]

Now I want to display a dynamic table next to the plot which shows values of my dataframe regarding to the currently plotted time.

Desired output (for the moment shown in the plot above):

```
id           34
amount       82
category     k3
```

This table output should update with the plot simultaneously, always showing the values of the current time (value of the slider) which is the `frame` attribute of the `plotly()` function

So the **key issue** is that I need to get access to the value of the animated slider but the function has no id, so I cannot call it.

Any idea how to get slider value? Or is there another approach where I can connect an animation to a table to achieve my goal?